# Only one image is displayed in rest api instead of multiple images

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a models where there is 2 table.One is rental which contains rental information and another is Gallery table which is associated with Rental table and each rent can have multiple images. I have designed an API using Django Rest Framework. My API displays rental information along with the image but only one image instead of all the image that is associated with its rent.

**my models.py**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,null=True,help_text=_("Description of the rental space"))


class Gallery(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class RentalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        field = ('id','ownerName','listingName')

class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rental = RentalSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        field = ('id','image','rental')

class GalleryListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Gallery.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GallerySerializer
    # filter_fields = ('listingName')
```

I want to show all the rental information along with its images(if multiple images then show all the images).What i am getting is if i have rental with 5 images then 5 times rental info is shown with  5 different images.

What have i done wrong in designing an API?

Answer (score 2):

```
edit :

class RentalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rental = serializers.RelatedField(source='Rental' , read_only=True , many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        field = ('id','ownerName','listingName','rental')
```

I haven't test this.

Comment: do i have to add that in GallerySerializer or RentalSerializer? I am getting following error AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, or set read_only=`True`.

Comment: rental = serializers.RelatedField(source='Rental' , read_only=True , many=True)

or

rental = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True , many=True)

Comment: You inherit the Rentalserializer in GallarySerializer so it comes on both

Comment: I dont get rental information. I only get rental id [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/upload/transitional-family-room_TDdnWmv.jpg",
        "rental": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/upload/room-design-11_OGlRS0i.jpg",
        "rental": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/upload/room-design-9_KmCuvvY.jpg",
        "rental": 1
    }]